# Python - parse, split and separate text into individual rows

Tags: python, csv, parsing, text, split

I have a text file with data I would like to import into an Access database.  The text file contains a few paragraphs that I want to go into one row. I've separated where I want each row by "@@@"

So here's an example of what I have:

@@@ I would like to go to school because it's so much fun. Blah Blah Blah Blah. I am having so much fun today. @@@ I am so happy for no reason. Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah. I am having so much fun today.

I would like this to appear like this:

> ID | Reporttext
>
> 1  | I would like to go to school because it's so much fun. Blah Blah
>   Blah Blah. I am having so much fun today.
>
> 2  | I am so happy for no reason. Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah. I am
>   having so much fun today.

However, I know I am close with my code, but I am getting this:

> ID | Reporttext
>
> 1  | I would like to go to school because it's so much fun. Blah Blah
>   Blah Blah.
>
> 2  | I am having so much fun today.
>
> 3  | I am so happy for no reason. Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah. I am
>   having so much
>
> 4  | I am having so much fun today.

I tried an IF statement to only add the ID if there was "@@@" in the line, but I couldn't get it to work. If I did that though, I figure it should work. I have ID and reporttext using a semicolon for the delimiter.

Here's my code:

```
import csv

with open("by2.txt") as txt, open('theoutput2.txt', 'a') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=';')
    writer.writerow(('ID', 'Reporttext'))
    Id = 1
    for line in txt:
        words = line.strip().split("@@@")
        for word in words:
            writer.writerow((id, word.strip()))
            id += 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can combine `split("@@@")` and `enumerate(iterable,start_index)` in conjunction with a generator expression:

```
t = """@@@ I would like to go to school because it's so much fun. Blah Blah Blah Blah. I am having so much fun today. @@@ I am so happy for no reason. Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah. I am having so much fun today."""

# split and enumerate(starting at 1)
# the if conditional inside the generator expression eleminates empty lines  
data = list(enumerate( (x.strip() for x in t.split("@@@") if x.strip()), 1))

print(data)
print("")

import csv
with open("t.txt", "w", newline = "") as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=';')
    writer.writerow(('ID', 'Reporttext'))
    writer.writerows(data)

print( open("t.txt").read())
```

Output:

```
# data
[(1, "I would like to go to school because it's so much fun. Blah Blah Blah Blah. I am having so much fun today."), 
 (2, 'I am so happy for no reason. Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah. I am having so much fun today.')]


# file
ID;Reporttext
1;I would like to go to school because it's so much fun. Blah Blah Blah Blah. I am having so much fun today.
2;I am so happy for no reason. Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah. I am having so much fun today.
```

Doku:

- [split()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)
- [enumerate()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate)